# How to write this simple cronjob in Linux (Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I need assistance in getting a cronjob to run properly in Linux (Debian).  (This is my first one).

I need a file to "run" once per hour a set number of times.  I got this far:

## crontab -e

no crontab for root - using an empty one

edited crontab file: 0 2-21 * * * /www/file.php

crontab: installing new crontab

This was designed to make the cronjob run beginning at 2am (or 200 hrs) and to run each hour on the hour until 2100 hrs.  I checked the database to see if the file did its thing at 2:10 and nothing had changed so it clearly didn't run.

I'm fairly new to Linux so there's probably a way to see what happened but I'm really wondering whether I wrote the Cronjob instruction correctly before I get into diagnosing.

Comment: # m h  dom mon dow   command

Comment: # 42 3-22 * * * /var/www/apache2-default/getUserDetails.php?friend=14522828

Comment: Did you check your Email for output/error messages from cron?

Answer (score 2):

Your crontab looks completely fine to me.

Are you sure that you have the appropriate execute bits set and the proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) so that the root can execute the file /www/file.php?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. It's 4am here right now so I will probably wait until the AM to read that.  I posted up exactly what I am entering in above (so it should have run starting at 3:42am).  I've tried it with or without the hashtag. Is it possible that the server time doesnt coincide with the computer time?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this:

> 42 3-22 * * * /var/www/apache2-default/getUserDetails.php?friend=14522828

You can't put the `?` there. It will consider the `?` along with the rest after it as part of the file name from the file system (it's looking for the file `getUserDetails.php?friend=14522828` at `/var/www/apache2-default`). What you can do is:

```
42 3-22 * * * /usr/bin/php-cgi /var/www/apache2-default/getUserDetails.php friend=14522828
```

(assuming the php-cgi executable is in /usr/bin, change accordingly if php is installed elsewhere)

Alternatively, you could edit getUserDetails.php and have the following line at the very top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi
<?php
[your code goes here]
...
```

Then make sure getUserDetails.php is executable by root (check via ls -l, assign via chmod) and then have the following schedule in cron:

```
42 3-22 * * * /var/www/apache2-default/getUserDetails.php friend=14522828
```

After that, you can monitor /var/log/cron for commands being run by crond. And then you can check root's mail (`mail` command) for the program output or errors encountered.

---

if on the other hand what you really had in your crontab was

```
0 2-21 * * * /www/file.php
```

Then I'm stumpped. The entry does look fine so what you need to make sure is that you can run the file manually in the command line (enter `/www/file.php` in the shell). Add the execute bits for it if not executable.

After that, check /var/log/cron as well as root's mail for both commands being executed and errors.